# Error while emailing CPU and Memory Utilization from a Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange, powershell

i can generate CPU and Memory Utilization of my laptop and email them to my email address. When i try to do the same thing for a Windows Server 2008, i get

**"new-object cannot load com type outlook.application".**

Windows Server doesn't has Outlook installed. **Does it require outlook to execute this script??**

```
## This is the location the script will save the output file

$OutputFile="C:\admin\ServerStatus.htm"     

## Replace these values with valid from and to email addresses

$smtpFrom = "emailaddress"

$smtpTo = "emailaddress"

$CPU = Get-WmiObject win32_processor | Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average

$Mem = gwmi -Class win32_operatingsystem |

Select-Object @{Name = "MemoryUsage"; Expression = {“{0:N2}” -f ((($_.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $_.FreePhysicalMemory)*100)/ $_.TotalVisibleMemorySize) }}

$Outputreport = "Test Server     

Average CPU = $($CPU.Average)%

Memory Used = $($MEM.MemoryUsage)%"

$Outputreport | out-file $OutputFile

$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application 
$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0) 
$Mail.Recipients.Add("emailaddress") 
$Mail.Subject = "PS1 Script TestMail" 
$Mail.Body += Get-Content $OutputFile

$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$Mail.Send()
```

Answer (score 2):

32-bit Powershell requires 32-bit Outlook objects and 64-bit powershell requires 64-bit Outlook.

So yes, you do need an Outlook installation to run the script.

**Edit:** Actually, you require the MAPI (Mailing API). Which comes with Outlook.

If you have an SMTP server available, you could use `Send-MailMessage` as described [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx)

Comment: Is there a way to generate CPU and Memory Utilization and email them without outlook?

Comment: You will need something to mail them, but if you do not have outlook, but do have SMTP, the SMTP option I included in my edit would be a good choice. :-)

Comment: cool thanks... just one question i replace  from $ol = New-Object until $ Mail.Send() with add send-MailMessage ?

Comment: It looks to me like that should do the trick indeed! (Given you provide send-MailMessage the correct parameters).

Comment: is SMTP server for outlook = smtp.outlook.com ?

Comment: You mean outlook.com?
`nslookup` reveals that they use the hotmail mail exchangers. 

I'm not sure if you can still use those, as I use our own SMTP servers and relays, but if you can do it, this should be the way: http://email.about.com/od/Outlook.com/f/What-Are-The-Outlook-com-Smtp-Server-Settings.htm

Comment: i forgot to add/ configure smtp server from server manager. I believe it might work.. i'll am not sure if my organization allows them to be installed in servers.

Answer (score 0):

Do something more awesome,

```
$computername="DC-server", "Hp-pc"

$AVGProc = Get-WmiObject -computername $computername win32_processor |  
Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average 
$OS = gwmi -Class win32_operatingsystem -computername $computername | 
Select-Object @{Name = "MemoryUsage"; Expression = {“{0:N2}” -f ((($_.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $_.FreePhysicalMemory)*100)/ $_.TotalVisibleMemorySize) }} 
#$vol = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_Volume -ComputerName $computername -Filter "DriveLetter = 'C:'" | 
#Select-object @{Name = "C PercentFree"; Expression = {“{0:N2}” -f  (($_.FreeSpace / $_.Capacity)*100) } } 

$result += [PSCustomObject] @{  
        ServerName = "$computername" 
        CPULoad = "$($AVGProc.Average)%" 
        MemLoad = "$($OS.MemoryUsage)%" 
        #CDrive = "$($vol.'C PercentFree')%" 
    } 

    $Outputreport = "<HTML><TITLE> Server Health Report </TITLE> 
                     <BODY background-color:peachpuff> 
                     <font color =""#99000"" face=""Microsoft Tai le""> 
                     <H2> Server Health Report </H2></font> 
                     <Table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0> 
                     <TR bgcolor=gray align=center> 
                       <TD><B>Server Name</B></TD> 
                       <TD><B>Avrg.CPU Utilization</B></TD> 
                       <TD><B>Memory Utilization</B></TD> " 

    Foreach($Entry in $Result)  

        {  
          if((($Entry.CpuLoad) -or ($Entry.memload)) -ge "80")  
          {  
            $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=red>"  
          }  
          else 
           { 
            $Outputreport += "<TR>"  
          } 
          $Outputreport += "<TD>$($Entry.Servername)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.CPULoad)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.MemLoad)</TD><TD align=center>"  
        } 
     $Outputreport += "</Table></BODY></HTML>"  


$Outputreport | out-file C:\Test.htm 

$smtpServer = "yoursmtpserver.com" 
$smtpFrom = "fromemailaddress@test.com" 
$smtpTo = "receipentaddress@test.com" 
$messageSubject = "Servers Health report" 
$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $smtpfrom, $smtpto 
$message.Subject = "PS1 Script TestMail"
$message.IsBodyHTML = $true 
$message.Body = "<head><pre>$style</pre></head>" 
$message.Body += Get-Content C:\test.htm 
$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer) 
$smtp.Send($message)
```

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-Script-to-Get-78687c5e